# run mpi program [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: mpi

I'm new in MPI and I'm trying to run this program I've written on a server ( It works fine on my laptop ). My laptop OS is ubuntu and the server OS is centos. On the server it compiles fine But when I run it with:

```
mpicxx main.cpp -o main
mpirun -np 1 main
```

I get this error:

```
problem with execution of main  on  www.judge.com:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It looks like it's trying to use a host. Is there a way to run my program on that server like how I do it on my laptop?
Also note that I don't have a root access on the server.

Comment: See what is meaning this error from http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mpirun1.html.

Comment: Try to use current directory in the path: ``mpirun -np 1 ./main`` - can this help?

Comment: It says it's either because a file doesn't exist or I don't have sufficient access. But what file? I also tried mpirun -np 1 ./main but got the same error with a small difference:   "... execution of ./main  on ..."

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into a similar problem.  I was troubleshooting my HDF5 installation using some test MPI programs found at the bottom of [this page](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_parallel).

```
user@host: mpiexec -n 4 f.out  
problem with execution of f.out  on  host:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory 
problem with execution of f.out  on  host:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory 
problem with execution of f.out  on  host:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory 
problem with execution of f.out  on  host:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I included the full path to the program, the error went away:

```
user@host: mpiexec -n 4 ~/testing/f.out 
Trying to create filef.h5                                                                        

MPI_FILE_OPEN succeeded
Trying to create filef.h5     

MPI_FILE_OPEN succeeded
Trying to create filef.h5       

MPI_FILE_OPEN succeeded
Trying to create filef.h5      

MPI_FILE_OPEN succeeded
```